# How to change the value of a cell using only integers in openpyxl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, openpyxl

Sorry if the title is unclear but I'm trying to use iteration to find the next free cell under a certain column in a spreadsheet. Here is the snippet of code I am trying to get to work:

```
c=0
for rows in s2.iter_rows(min_row=1,max_col=100, max_row=1):
    for cell in rows:
        c = c + 1
        print(cell.value)
        if cell.value == "Prom":
            print("Working so far")
            r=2
            for columns in s2.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=c, max_col=c, max_row=1000):
                if s2.cell(row=r, column=c).value != None:
                    print("Nope")
                    r = r + 1
                else:
                    s2.cell(row=r, column=c) = "Grant"
                    break
            break
```

`s2` is the name of the sheet I'm editing. What's happening here is the code goes through columns till it finds a cell with the value `Prom`, updating `c` each time, which is the column the loop is on. Then the next loop starts which goes through the rows on the column that `Prom` is on, updating `r` each iteration to get the correct value for the row. This bit is supposed to keep going till it finds a cell with no value, however the first line in the `else` statement obviously produces an error. I'm aware that to update a cell you have to use the `sheet["A1"] = x` format but I can't see a way to do that here.

If you are aware of a way to do what I'm trying to, please let me know! Sorry if this is a silly question and has an obvious solution, I couldn't find many people with similar problems.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The problem is you're not assigning the value correctly. You're supposed to use `s2.cell(row=r, column=c).value`.

Comment: @AliasCartellano yes thank you! I don't know how I somehow got it in my head that you couldn't assign values to cells through that method. It also didn't help that I had the maximum and minimum columns and rows mixed up in my loop - that's totally on me. Thanks again!

Comment: Why the nested loop?

Comment: @CharlieClark honestly, I'm not entirely sure but it works and that's enough for me.